# How do I change the shape of a div

Tags: html, css

I was wondering how I change the shape of a div with CSS. I have done some research on it and found out about the 'skew' option, however, none of the examples I have seen give the shape I'm looking for. Here is an image of what I'm looking for.

[image: Image 1]

Comment: The examples are there to show you how it works so you can adjust it to your needs. That's how you learn new things, not by copy-pasting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many different approaches and the best you can do when learning CSS is to try it on your own. So before having a look at the below approach I suggest to look at these resources:

- [How do CSS triangles work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073484/how-do-css-triangles-work)
- [The Shapes of CSS](https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/)

```css
.pattern-column {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: darkgrey;
  width: 60px;
}
.pattern-column div {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 100px solid darkgrey;
  border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
  margin-left: -40px;
  margin-top: -30px;
}
.pattern-column div:nth-child(2n) {
  border-left: 100px solid grey;
  border-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
}
.pattern-column div:nth-child(3n) {
  border-right-color: #ccc;      
  border-left-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="pattern-column">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I had a look at those links, and will more than likely use them a lot now that I know about them. The code was also what I was looking for, so with a bit of tweaking, I should be able to get it to work. Thanks for the response.

Comment: One question, it may be a very simple answer, but how would I scale it all up so that it fills the whole browser window?

Comment: It took me a while to get into the right direction, but it seems pretty time consuming to make it perfectly work and not as easy as I thought. This is what I came up with: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lcye6eyv/). Using triangles like described above isn't the way to go then, because you can't set the border-width to a percentage width. Anyway I hope my attempt can help you. Otherwise you could think about using a repeating background image.

Answer (score 0):

If it is pixel perfect I would create a container with position:relative and define the width and height and set it to overflow:hidden. Then create three divs to be contained inside and use transform:rotate(XXdeg) for each item with position:absolute and then z-index them to overlay eachother accordingly. Give that a go.

Comment: can you give example